# how to display subtext under UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I have two arrays1)image_array and 2)text_array.I know how to display images
 and text .

```
 cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[text objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    cell.textLabel.text = [arry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

it's showing like

```
image1     text1
image2     text2
image3     text3
|
|
image7     text7
```

But I need like

```
    image1
    text1

    image2
    text2

|
|
    image7
    text7
```

Please give me any idea.Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: Use custom table cell in that case, it will give you more control

Comment: You need to use custom table cell that can be found here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19148582/custom-table-view-cell

Comment: Yes! Custom cell can solve problem easily.

Comment: Hey @ios start check my answer.,,

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a custom cell and setting their image view and label frame properties?

```
cell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(XORIG, 0, WI, HI);
cell.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(XORIG, cell.imageView.frame.origin.y + cell.imageView.frame.size.height, WL, HL);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

set cell style to subtitle and then

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[text objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = = [arry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell %d",indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell = nil;

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        UIImageView *myimagview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 40, 40)];
        myimagview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:myimagview];
        [myimagview release];


        UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc]init];
        lbl.frame=CGRectMake(10,60, 250, 20);
        lbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:14];
        lbl.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        lbl.text=@"";
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lbl];
        [lbl release];


        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

    }
    return cell;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 90;
}
```